# What key combinations should be used by Windows application to avoid conflicts?

Tags: windows, language-agnostic, keyboard-shortcuts, user-experience

I have an application that runs in the background on a Windows OS, and I want to add HotKeys or shortcuts to access functionality.  Since the application will capture system wide key presses, I don't want to interfere with standard Windows shortcuts or standard application specific shortcuts (e.g. Ctrl+S, Alt+F4).

Is there a group of key combinations set aside for application specific use, or is it just a matter of finding unused combinations and using them?  Are there any standards when it comes to this type of thing?

Comment: Since you haven't mentioned it - whatever you pick, make sure there's a way to configure it to any other value.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a convention for adding your own that would avoid those created by others.  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> RegisterHotKey fails if the keystrokes specified for the hot key have already been registered by another hot key.

So you could have a list of hot keys.  Try to register each one until you succeed.  Even better: let the user choose.

Comment: Even if you let the user choose, you should always provide a sensible default. 99% of users will keep the default.

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be to pick a standard start to flag your application.  Perhaps all your application's key combinations could start with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Keypad 0</kbd> followed by a command letter.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Keypad 0</kbd> is unusual enough that other applications are unlikely to use it, and after that combination you can use common keys: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Keypad 0</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> for Copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Keypad 0</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for paste etc.